# Strip leading/trailing spaces and commas in Excel

Tags: excel, trim, vba

This seems like such a simple requirement, that I feel like I am missing something obvious.

I have an Excel spreadsheet with "dirty" text data in, containing text and unwanted leading and trailing, spaces, commas and newlines. I would like to TRIM references to these cells of all those characters.

Note: I don't want to replace all those characters, since they legitimately appear within the cell text - it is just when at the start or end of the cell text (i.e. value) that I want to trim them off.

The text data consists of names of people and schools, for cleaning and importing into a CRM.

So, is there a function built in, or do I need to write one? I feel spoiled by the number of string filtering functions in PHP ;-)

Comment: Just to add, these cells I am cleaning have every combination and order of commas, spaces and newlines you can think of, so I can't just strip each off in turn.

Comment: Are you doing this in Excel or is a vb/c# program creating this file?

Comment: The data is all supplied in Excel. The idea is to produce worksheets within Excel that I can export as CSV for importing into the CRM. There is this minor cleaning, but most of the work involves validation and lookups of tables of states/counties/salutations etc.

Comment: The only built-in functions will trim spaces. For other characters you'll need to build your own.

Comment: Try building or running a vba script, and build it into the excel file that can strip out what you don't want.

Comment: I thought that would be the case, which does strike me as slightly bizarre, considering spaces are no different to tabs or newlines when it comes to trimming white space, so why put spaces on a pedestal and ignore other white space? I found this page with the solution, also now posted in the original question: http://www.ehow.com/how_8347417_make-functions-excel.html

Comment: I've done this now. I'm not a VB expert, so did not want to spend hours learning that for this one simple problem, but thankfully the answer was out there when REs suddenly occurred to me.

Comment: Thx for posting your workinjg code. Note that `\s` will remove all whitepaces (rather than specifying [ \r\n] etc.

Comment: Good point about the white space match. I've updated the sample code to reflect this.

Comment: Please don't edit your question to include answers. That is what the Answer section is for...

Comment: My final solution moved to an answer of its own.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is well suited to a regexp

The code below [adapted from this article](http://www.experts-exchange.com/Software/Office_Productivity/Office_Suites/MS_Office/Excel/A_2684-Using-varinat-arrays-in-VBA-for-large-scale-data.html?articleID=2684&titleurl=Using-varinat-arrays-in-VBA-for-large-scale-data) uses this regexp
`"[,\s]*(.+?)[,\s]*$"`
to remove any leading and/or trailing whitespaces/commas while leaving any such characters within the text body intact

It will replace your existing data in-situ

```
Sub RemoveDirt()
Dim rng1 As Range
Dim rngArea As Range
Dim lngRow As Long
Dim lngCol As Long
Dim lngCalc As Long
Dim objReg As Object
Dim X()


On Error Resume Next
Set rng1 = Application.InputBox("Select range for the replacement of leading zeros", "User select", Selection.Address, , , , , 8)
If rng1 Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
On Error GoTo 0

'See Patrick Matthews excellent article on using Regular Expressions with VBA
Set objReg = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
objReg.MultiLine = True
objReg.Pattern = "[,\s]*(.+?)[,\s]*$"

'Speed up the code by turning off screenupdating and setting calculation to manual

'Disable any code events that may occur when writing to cells
With Application
    lngCalc = .Calculation
    .ScreenUpdating = False
    .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    .EnableEvents = False
End With

'Test each area in the user selected range

'Non contiguous range areas are common when using SpecialCells to define specific cell types to work on
For Each rngArea In rng1.Areas
    'The most common outcome is used for the True outcome to optimise code speed
    If rngArea.Cells.Count > 1 Then
       'If there is more than once cell then set the variant array to the dimensions of the range area
       'Using Value2 provides a useful speed improvement over Value. On my testing it was 2% on blank cells, up to 10% on non-blanks
        X = rngArea.Value2
        For lngRow = 1 To rngArea.Rows.Count
            For lngCol = 1 To rngArea.Columns.Count
                'replace the leading zeroes
                X(lngRow, lngCol) = objReg.Replace(X(lngRow, lngCol), "$1")
            Next lngCol
        Next lngRow
        'Dump the updated array sans dirt over the initial range
        rngArea.Value2 = X
    Else
        'caters for a single cell range area. No variant array required
        rngArea.Value = objReg.Replace(rngArea.Value, "$1")
    End If
Next rngArea

'cleanup the Application settings
With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = True
    .Calculation = lngCalc
    .EnableEvents = True
End With

Set objReg = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: I used the code I pasted into the question in the end, as it was simpler, but will keep your version handy for the future, as it looks very handy. I did not want to fix the data in-situ however, because in the spreadsheet world I like to keep all the working-out from source to final data, as it makes finding the inevitable mistakes, incorrect assumptions, and lost data a lot easier.

Answer (score 1):

I have found this code, which I pasted in as a module into my spreadsheet:

```
Option Explicit

Function ReReplace(ReplaceIn, _
    ReplaceWhat As String, ReplaceWith As String, Optional IgnoreCase As Boolean = False)

    Dim RE As Object
    Set RE = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
    RE.IgnoreCase = IgnoreCase
    RE.Pattern = ReplaceWhat
    RE.Global = True
    ReReplace = RE.Replace(ReplaceIn, ReplaceWith)
End Function
```

This provides a replace function that supports REs (why doesn't Excel do that itself? It has only been around since 1987 - I had it on my Atari ST, note that you can add more than ten cells before it crashed!). This cell function is able to do the trimming I need:

```
=ReReplace('source worksheet'!cell_reference, "^[\s,]+|[\s,]+$", "")
```

This works beautifully.

(Note: this answer moved from the question text, where it really should not have been.)

Answer (score 0):

Recursive function to remove comma and trailing spaces. Pure VBA..

```
Function removetrailcomma(txt As String) As String
    If Right(txt, 1) = " " Or Right(txt, 1) = "," Then
        removetrailcomma = removetrailcomma(Left(txt, Len(txt) - 1))
    Else
        removetrailcomma = txt
    End If
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried this using two steps

1. By removing spaces
2. By removing comma

**For removing leading and trailing spaces**

Use direct function `TRIM(A1)`

**For removing leading and trailing comma**

```
=MID(A1,IF(FIND(",",A1)=1,2,1),IF(RIGHT(A1)=",",LEN(A1)-2,LEN(A1)))
```

or

```
=SUBSTITUTE(TRIM(SUBSTITUTE(A1,","," "))," ",",")
```